# Javascript XMLHttpRequest: delegate_blocked_by = "Opening Files"

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am implementing an upload file input and when I try to upload the file to the server using XMLHttpRequest I am getting this error:

> delegate_blocked_by = "Opening Files"

What could be the cause for this type of error ?

Note: I can see this is the error using "chrome://net-export/", the XMLHttpRequest `onerror` is called but there is no error description there that I could find.

[image: Network log]

Comment: Please post your log output as text, not as an image

Comment: Regarding formatted text vs images of text: this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: @MarioVarchmin I see, will do next time. normally i would put the text but i wanted to blur certain parts of it.